# macOS: The cursor in Terminal won’t blink

Tags: macos, terminal

Is the macOS Terminal.app cursor not blinking the default macOS behavior?

How can one configure it to blink?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default behaviour for macOS Terminal.app cursor is to not blink.

To configure cursor type and blink, in Terminal.app menu bar go to Terminal → Preferences... → Profiles and under **Cursor** check **Blink cursor**.

[image]

Comment: There does not appear to be a way to configure the rate of the blinking.  Using `defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriodOn -float 200` and friends affects the rate in some applications, but not in Terminal or iTerm/iTerm2.